# Workaround for Apache POI 3.10 Bug 56274

Tags: apache-poi

Upgrading from poi-3.8 to poi-3.10 caused a bug where xlsx files loaded as a template using XSSF, added with some data and written with SXSSF resulted in corrupt files.

Opening the resulting files with Excel 2013 results in the following Yes/No dialog:
"We found a problem with some content in 'Filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."
Clicking yes shows the recovery result dialog, with a list of repaired table*.xml files under /xl/tables in the internal excel structure.

This is a known bug in Apache POI 3.10
[Bug 56274](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56274)

It is fixed in later version of Apache POI. But due to my product limitation I can not upgrade to higher version and have to continue using 3.10

So is there any workaround (calling different method, setting some flags,additional programmatic work after file is generated etc. )
Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: The patch to fix it is included in the bug you linked to, if you really must stick with an old version, why not apply the patch to your own local old 3.10 build?

Comment: @Gagravarr Problem is that I can not touch/change jars

Comment: You're using an old version of a library with [lots of known and subsequently fixed issues](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.10-FINAL), just point your team at the [fix list](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.10-FINAL) + the bug and ask them to move to something more recent!